# Apache, MySQL, and clean URLs as queries

Tags: mysql, apache, drupal

I'm interested in configuring Apache similarly to Drupal in the way it uses clean URLs as MySQL queries and can create path aliases. I have no idea how to do any of this, so please help get me started :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not really configuring 'Apache' per say, but `.htaccess` or rather `mod_rewrite` module under Apache.

Here is a quick tutorial on how to go about doing what you need:

**http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite**

Comment: @maxedison: In addition you may want to read this article about REST @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer.

Comment: Thanks Jakub. I won't have time to give it a try for a couple more days, but it looks simple enough.